# 19th Century Patent Data

Tags: data-request

Any 19th century patent data with geo-referenced locations of the submitter? So, for each city or county, it lists the number of patents filed in a given year/month etc?

Comment: You'll have to do a little work, but http://www.uspto.gov/patents-application-process/search-patents notes: "The USPTO houses full text for patents issued from 1976 to the present and PDF images for all patents from 1790 to the present."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Patent Search Engine and get customize result, using required date fields like Filing Date used from 1800-01-01 to 1900-12-31. [**See here**](https://patents.google.com/?before=filing:19001231&after=filing:18000101&sort=old)

After getting required results, you can download patents data using download option in csv, xlsx etc. format. See image below :
[image: Patents Data]